# How to run an ipa file from a Flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, ipa

Hi I'm new to Flutter and I hava specific use case that I don't know if it is possible.

Is it possible to run a IPA file for another app when I press a button in Flutter.

The IPA file comes from a XCode project, so if that is not possible is there any way to convert the XCode code to Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run a IPA file for another app when I press a button in Flutter.

Do you mean you want to open a different app on pressing a button in your flutter app, if yes, then sorry you can't open any app in iOS however you can do that in android using [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) plugin.

> The IPA file comes from a XCode project, so if that is not possible is there any way to convert the XCode code to Flutter.

If you mean you have an app already written in Swift or Objective-C and you want to convert it in Flutter app, then again sorry there is no way to do that, you'll have to write the code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

First, an .ipa (iOS App Store Package) file is an iOS application archive file which stores an iOS app. It is kind of binary file and cannot be converted to source code (Dart in Flutter or Swift in XCode)

Second, I think there is currently no way to convert existing XCode project (written in Swift or Objective-C) to Flutter project. You have to manually code in Flutter your self.